# How do I pass in parameters into arrow functions in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, parameter-passing, arrow-functions

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7abJ.png)
I want the "elem" parameter of my component to be another component based on the boolean that is passed into my arrow function.

I have tried passing in "mobile" as a parameter into these arrow functions as it was a parameter of my <Homebar> hook. I'm not exactly sure how local variables work in JSX. Should I instead pass in "mobile=mobile" to set the value as a default param value? Should I just hard code an if else statement before my return? Or are arrow functions not possible within return statements?

Comment: What is that elem prop you use? The error likely lies there

Answer (score 0):

`ReactJS` at the base level uses `JavaScript` itself, so you can pass in parameters the same way as JavaScript callbacks and functions.

Example:

```js
import React from 'react';

const Component = () => {
  const handleClick = (name) => {
    // Handle the click event with the param
    console.log('Recording parameter:', name);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick('Bob')}> // pass parameter here
        Click me (Bob)
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Component;
```

For passing parameter with default value, you can pass it as `(param = true)`

Although, this is available in the documentation itself. You should refer that first in order to understand React and JS:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Answer (score 0):

Your `elem` properties don't appear to accept a function so it looks to me like you just want some [conditional rendering](https://react.dev/learn/conditional-rendering)

```jsx
return (
  <div className="navbar">
    <Leftbar elem={<Contact pos="left" />} />
    <Midbar elem={mobile && <Socials pod="mid" />} />
    <Rightbar
      elem={
        <>
          {mobile && <Socials pos="left" />}
          <Sections pos="right" />
        </>
      }
    />
  </div>
);
```

---

FYI Boolean props should not be set with `={true}`. You can simplify your `Homebar` component using the following

```jsx
return <Homebar mobile={screenSize.width <= 600} />
```